# How to open a new tab with SCRIPT SRC

Tags: html, src

I'm trying to add a payment button to my web page (wix). When clicked, it opens in the same iframe like a widget, but I would like it to open in a new tab when clicked. `target="_blank"` does not work.

Example code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://www.example.com./integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js"
data-preference-id="example" data-source="button">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**With Bootstrap you can use an *anchor* like a *button*.**

---

**OR use *style* to customize *link* as to appear like a *button***.

---

**And use target="_blank" to open the link in a new tab.**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        

        <a class="btn btn-success" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">open google in new tab</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a link in a new tab from velo, I made a video workaround below:

https://joelgrayson.com/open-in-new-tab-wix-code
https://youtu.be/7yp-kLGu1Yw

Essentially, you cannot use `<a href='' target='_blank'>` in velo, but you can do it in an HTML frame. In the workaround, I messaged the HTML frame from velo. Upon receiving the message, the HTML frame opened using `<a href='' target='_blank'`.